# Need advice on the best way to roll my own routing for a PHP framework

Tags: php, rest, routes

I currently have a PHP framework I wrote which relies on messy URL variables to know what pages to display or data to return, e.g.

http://someurl.com/myapp/index.php?page=notes&id=34 //displays html page
http://someurl.com/myapp/action.php?itemIdCode=notes&id=34&view=compact //gets JSON/html for ajax calls

I want to now program my own routing so that the URLs look something like this:

http://someurl.com/myapp/page/note/34 //returns a full page for browser calls
http://someurl.com/myapp/data/notes/34 //returns JSON for AJAX calls
http://someurl.com/myapp/view/notes/34/compact //returns HTML for AJAX calls

Here are some questions:

1. Are there any syntax rules that you would recommend in order to maintain standardize REST syntax (e.g. if I use a front end javascript library which expects some standard).
2. Are there any syntax rules that you would recommend in order to improve SEO, e.g. using plurals names or singular names, using nouns/verbs, the order, etc.
3. What do you do if you have a number of bits of key/values you want to send e.g. to maintain state on a page, do you just send URL variables at the end of the routing url like this: http://someurl.com/myapp/page/note/34?searchOpen=true&sortColumn=city&order=asc
4. What is the .htaccess code I need to capture all URL calls in index.php so that I can process the URL without the browser being sent into sub-directories etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, look into the Symfony Router, since it is basically standalone:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html

You might also find these two videos interesting:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzgCzjMdvRE

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoiaSkRCObY

> Are there any syntax rules that you would recommend in order to improve SEO, e.g. using plurals names or singular names, using nouns/verbs, the order, etc.

Use what is the most natural. Examples:

- `GET /posts` is a list of posts.
- `GET /posts/2` or `GET /posts:2` seems natural for page 2 of the same list of posts.
- `GET /posts/1-3` or `GET /posts:1-3` seems natural for pages 1 to 3 of the same list of posts if you're using infinite scrolling.
- `GET /post/1` or `GET /post:1` could be post id 1.
- `PUT /post/1` or `PUT /post:1` would update post id 1.
- `GET /post` or  `GET /post/new` or `GET /post:new` would be natural for a new post editor.
- `POST /post` or `POST /post/new` or `POST /post:new` would be natural to actually insert the new post.
- etc.

> What do you do if you have a number of bits of key/values you want to send e.g. to maintain state on a page, do you just send URL variables at the end of the routing url like this: http://someurl.com/myapp/page/note/34?searchOpen=true&sortColumn=city&order=asc

Imho, use a query string for that type of thing. Else urls and routing rules get very messy very quickly. (For an epic example of how messy things get, check out the WordPress rewrite logic related to ANDed and ORed taxonomies.)

> What is the .htaccess code I need to capture all URL calls in index.php so that I can process the URL without the browser being sent into sub-directories etc.

Typically:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```